# CodeIgniter: Message: Uninitialized string offset: 2...using insert_batch

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to insert multiple rows using the function insert_batch.
The values come from a form.

**Controller**

```
$product_sub_desc_en = $this->input->post('list-en');
$product_sub_desc_ru = $this->input->post('list-ru');
$id = $this->input->post('product-id');

$data_description_list =array();
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
$data_description_list[$i] = array(
       'english' => $product_desc_en[$i], 
       'russian' => $product_desc_ru[$i],
       'productID'=>$id
);
}
$this->get_shop_products->insert_new_product_description_list($data_description_list);
```

**Model**

```
public function insert_new_product_description_list($data){
$this->db->insert_batch('product', $data); 
}
```

After calling the query I get following errors:

> Message: Uninitialized string offset: 2
>       ...till...// Message: Uninitialized string offset: 9

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Print out $data before inserting `var_dump($data);exit;` and you will see is structure of it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Message: Uninitialized string offset: 2 ...till...// Message:
>   Uninitialized string offset: 9

This error would occur if any of the following variables were actually strings or null instead of arrays, in which case accessing them with an array syntax `$arr[$i]`.

From [Codeigniter User Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

The first parameter will contain the name of the POST item you are looking for:

```
$this->input->post('some_data');
```

The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist.

So I suspect you may be having problem with `$this->input->post('some_name')`

It's always good to validate before processing, in current context you can do something like this

```
$product_sub_desc_en = $this->input->post('list-en');
$product_sub_desc_ru = $this->input->post('list-ru');
$id = $this->input->post('product-id');

if( $product_sub_desc_en && $product_sub_desc_ru && $id )
{
    // Do whatever you want here
}else
{
   // Error log
   log_message('error', 'Something went wrong with post data --> '.print_r($this->input->post(),true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_sub_desc_en = $this->input->post('list-en');
$product_sub_desc_ru = $this->input->post('list-ru');
$id = $this->input->post('product-id');

$data_description_list =array();
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  $data_description_list[] = array(
   'english' => $product_desc_en[$i], 
   'russian' => $product_desc_ru[$i],
   'productID'=>$id

   );
}
$this->get_shop_products->insert_new_product_description_list($data_description_list);
```

make you controller code as above, it will work. Look only change in `$data_description_list` in for loop

let me know if this not fix your problem